# Search one table and use result to search another table

Tags: mysql, select

I want to make a search on one table that returns a value to be used in search on different table.

I have this code, which looks for a team code in the club table:

```
SELECT Team, Teamcode
  FROM epl.club
  WHERE Teamcode = 
    (SELECT Teamcode 
      FROM epl.club 
      WHERE Team='Manchester City');
```

Now I want to use the resulting Teamcode for a select on the matches table.

I have this code that searches the matches table and finds all the matches with a given team code but I need it to get the code from the first search above.

```
Select *
  from epl.matches
  where HomeTeam = 35
     or AwayTeam = 35
       and FTR like "A"
     or FTR like "H";
```

Another thing I don't understand is that I want to make that it would just return the line only if `HomeTeam=35'= and '=FTR is A or FTR is H` or if `AwayTeam=35 and FTR is A or FTR is H`, but what the code does is that it returns all the lines even if they contain the 35 but only contain the H or A in the FTR column.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use parentheses in your boolean expression:

```
 SELECT *
   FROM epl.matches
  WHERE (HomeTeam = 35 or AwayTeam = 35)
    AND (FTR like "A" or FTR like "H")
```

This is because [`AND` has a higher operator precedence as `OR`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/operator-precedence.html).

You can combine the queries with a join:

```
    SELECT Team, Teamcode FROM epl.club c 
INNER JOIN epl.matches m ON (m.HomeTeam = c.Teamcode or m.AwayTeam = c.Teamcode)
     WHERE (c.Team = 'Manchester City')
       AND (m.FTR like "A" or m.FTR like "H")
```

*Additional info*:

Here is a very simple explanation how a 'INNER JOIN' can be understood - just if you don't know this already. If you have two tables:

```
{ Table: Club }----------------| { Table: Matches }----------|
|                              | |                           |
| Teamcode | Team              | | HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTR | 
|----------+-------------------| |----------+----------+-----|
| 35       | Manchester City   | | 38       | 39       | A   |
| 38       | Arsenal London    | | 38       | 35       | A   |
| 39       | Leeds United      | | 35       | 39       | H   |
|----------+-------------------| | 38       | 35       | A   |
                                 | 39       | 38       | H   |
                                 |----------+----------+-----|
```

an `INNER JOIN` between the tables `club` and `matches` means that of all row combinations of the two tables only the rows are included in the result if the join condition `m.HomeTeam = c.Teamcode or m.AwayTeam = c.Teamcode` is met. If you restrict `club.Team` to `'Manchester City'` you would have the following result for the join:

```
{ Table: Join Result }------|
|                           |
| HomeTeam | AwayTeam | FTR | 
|----------+----------+-----|
| 38       | 35       | A   |
| 35       | 39       | H   |
| 38       | 35       | A   |
|----------+----------+-----|
```

It takes some time to get used to declarative style of the join syntax but it helps you to structure your queries (opposed to multiple `FROM` tables and nested `SELECT` subqueries). Furthermore, the SQL query optimizer can handle an `INNER JOIN` better then nested subqueries in most cases.

Comment: for some reason when I use the combined query code it returns 0 entries but if I change the `WHERE (c.Teamcode = 'Manchester City')` to `WHERE (c.Teamcode = '35')` it shows up fine.

Comment: I need your initial code to work because there's no point changing it to 35 i could just use the first code instead.

Comment: @EligijusTrembelis Ooops! I mixed up `Team` and `Teamcode`. I corrected the answer and added a little explanation. You should really read about joins how joins work and how they can be useful to create quieries.

Comment: @EligijusTrembelis If it's alright you can accept my answer again.

Answer (score 0):

First query could just be:

```
 SELECT 
 Team, 
 Teamcode
 FROM epl.club
 WHERE Team='Manchester City';
```

Why a subquery on the same table when you can access directly the Team field?

Then you can do:

```
SELECT *
FROM epl.matches
WHERE HomeTeam = (SELECT Teamcode FROM epl.club WHERE Team='Manchester City')
   OR AwayTeam = (SELECT Teamcode FROM epl.club WHERE Team='Manchester City')
   AND FTR like "A"
   OR FTR like "H";
```

Comment: I did not consider your issue on the where. @ventiseis got it perfect!